# How to Webscrape a UL class tag using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rotten-tomatoes

I'm writing to web scrape in python using Beautiful soup to get Box office amount $64.3M. But I'm unable to do so.

```
<ul class="content-meta info">
                
                
                <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Box Office (Gross USA):</div>
                    <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">$64.3M</div>
                </li>
                
                
                <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Runtime:</div>
                    <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">
                        <time datetime="P2h 4mM">
                            2h 4m
                        </time>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                
                <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Distributor:</div>
                    <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">
                        
                        Universal Pictures
                        
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                
                <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Production Co:</div>
                    <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">
                        
                        Universal Pictures, 
                        
                        Blumhouse Productions, 
                        
                        Dark Universe, 
                        
                        Goalpost Pictures
                        
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                
                <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Sound Mix:</div>
                    <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">
                        Dolby Atmos
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                
                <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Aspect Ratio:</div>
                    <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">
                        Scope (2.35:1)
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                
            </ul>
```

I tried multiple syntaxes but nothing worked.

`z = soup.find("ul").get("movie-info-item-value")`

`for tag in soup.find_all("ul"): print("{0}: {1}".format(tag.name, tag.text))`

`x = soup.select('movie-info-item-value')`

`x = soup.select('class').get('movie-info-item-value')`

I'm new to python and webscraping. Any help will be deeply appreciated. TIA!!

Comment: Could you share the URL ?

Comment: Updated answer for full HTML. Try `elt = soup.find(text="Box Office (Gross USA):").parent.parent.find('div', class_="meta-value").text`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify target attributes in find() and find_all() for matching a `<ul>` element with class attribute and value of "content-meta info" with the `class_` shortcut or a dictionary object for the attributes to match.

Try this:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ul class="content-meta info">                                
    <li class="meta-row clearfix" data-qa="movie-info-item">
        <div class="meta-label subtle" data-qa="movie-info-item-label">Box Office (Gross USA):</div>
        <div class="meta-value" data-qa="movie-info-item-value">$64.3M</div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
elt = soup.find("ul", class_="content-meta info")\
          .find('li', {'data-qa': 'movie-info-item'})\
          .find('div', class_="meta-value")
print(elt.text)
```

If HTML has multiple "ul" elements with same class then try this to first find the Box Office element.

```python
elt = (soup
       .find(text="Box Office (Gross USA):")
       .parent
       .parent
       .find('div', class_="meta-value")
       )
print(elt.text)
```

**Output:**

```
$64.3M
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The sample code works well as the tag is in the HTML. Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I scrape from the entire website. The HTML page content in the code directly picks up the first item in the list. I tried to use a for loop and tried printing with an index both didn't work. Your code gave me a new direction to look at. Thank you!

for el in elt:
         soup.find("ul", class_="content-meta info")\
          .find('li', {'data-qa': 'movie-info-item'})\
          .find('div', class_="meta-value")
print (el)

Comment: elt=soup.findAll('li', {'data-qa': 'movie-info-item'})\

elt[8].text[25:30]

Answer (score 0):

Compare to XPath syntax (using `lxml`):

```
from lxml import html

....

tree = html.fromstring(content) # content here is a HTML content of your page
box_office = tree.xpath('string(//div[@data-qa="movie-info-item-label"][contains(., "Box Office")]/following-sibling::div[1]/text())')
```

I have a **single** expression that extract information you need in a simple human way (find a `div` tag that have predefined `data-qa` attribute and that contains some predefined text and next extract a text of the following `div`). IMHO, much more readable compared to CSS selectors.